# How to add new Employee without declaring a lot of object names

Tags: java, eclipse, oop, jakarta-ee

I have a small assignment on adding and displaying different types of employees(diff. departments) at work and different salary & benefits, using OOP approach. I am quite not sure if my code is correct in terms of code reuse & if did I really meet the OOP coding approach...So far I have displayed 1 employee each type/department, I made them as a class name.(see code below). My question is if I add a new employee I'm going to declare another object of type Employee again. And what if there will be a lot of employees, I will be having a lot of objects. How do I lessen that and may I know if my OOP coding approach is correct so far? Ty very much! Here is my code:

```
        //this is my parent class which implements an interface...
        public abstract class Employees implements ICompensation{
        private String fname;
        private String lname;
        private char gender;
        private String address;
        private double salary;

        public String getfname(){
            return this.fname;
        }

        public void setfname(String fname){
            this.fname = fname;
        }

        public String getLname() {
            return lname;
        }

        public void setLname(String lname) {
            this.lname = lname;
        }

        public char getGender() {
            return gender;
        }

        public void setGender(char gender) {
            this.gender = gender;
        }

        public String getAddress() {
            return address;
        }

        public void setAddress(String address) {
            this.address = address;
        }

        public double getSalary() {
            return salary;
        }

        public void setSalary(double salary) {
            this.salary = salary;
        }
        }

    // this is a Developer type of employee

        public class Developer extends Employees{

        public Developer(String fname,String lname, char gender,String address, double salary){
            setfname(fname);
            setLname(lname);
            setGender(gender);
            setAddress(address);
            setSalary(salary);
        }

        @Override
        public double calculateSalary() {
            double salary = getSalary();
            salary += 10;
            return salary;
        }

        @Override
        public void print() {
            System.out.println(this.getClass());
            System.out.println(this.getfname());
            System.out.println(this.getLname());
            System.out.println(this.getGender());
            System.out.println(this.getAddress());
            System.out.println(this.calculateSalary());}}

    //this is QA type of employee

        public class QA extends Employees{

        public QA(String fname,String lname,char gender,String address,double salary) {
            setfname(fname);
            setLname(lname);
            setGender(gender);
            setAddress(address);
            setSalary(salary);
        }

        @Override
        public double calculateSalary() {
            double salary = getSalary();
            salary = salary + 20;
            return salary;

        }

        @Override
        public void print() {
            System.out.println(this.getClass());
            System.out.println(this.getfname());
            System.out.println(this.getLname());
            System.out.println(this.getGender());
            System.out.println(this.getAddress());
            System.out.println(this.calculateSalary()); 
        }
        }
```

I have another 2 classes which are BA & Manager class but I wont include here because it's just have the same contents to the other derived class.

```
    //so here is my Interface
        public interface ICompensation {
        double calculateSalary();
        void print();
        }

    //and here is my main method.
    import java.util.*;

public class main {
    public static void main(String[] args){
        Employees dev = new Developer("Janel","Logrono",'M',"Alabang",491);
        Employees qa = new QA("juan","Sir",'M',"Taguig",1240);
        Employees ba = new BA("pedro","Lyn",'F',"Taguig",1150);
        Employees manager = new Manager("sebastian","rods",'M',"USA",555399);

        ArrayList<Employees> ls = new ArrayList<>();    
        ls.add(dev);
        ls.add(qa);
        ls.add(ba);
        ls.add(manager);

        for(Employees e : ls){
            e.print();
            System.out.println();
        }
    }
}
```

How do add another employee w/o declaring a lot of objects and may I know if my OOP coding approach is correct so far, I think there are a lot of redundant codes here, how to lessen it? thx!

Comment: "...add another employee without declaring a lot of objects..." How do you define "a lot"?  And what exactly do you think you have too many of?

Comment: what is so different between a developer and a QA that you need a different class to handle it? would you love the need to implement a new class if you need to handle a janitor? or a CEO? what happens when your developer joins the QA team (maybe just for one or two weeks)? the "type" of employee is more likely a field on your employee class rather than a hierarchy of classes (maybe name it "role" or "position")

Comment: maybe you want to reduce your lines of code with something like `ls.add(new Developer("Janel","Logrono",'M',"Alabang",491));`

Comment: @KevinAnderson im going to have alot of object type employee like Employee dev1, then if I will add another im going to declare another Employee dev2; that will become too many right

Comment: @S.Piller so does it mean I will only have one class only w/c is the Employee(parent class)?

Comment: Well, you certainly don't need to have an individual  variable for each individual employee . You can do as @fantaghirocco suggested and add the new employees directly to the list without first assigning them to _any_ variables. Or just create _one_ variable and re-use it for each new employee; but remember that you then have to add each employee to your list before creating the next employee.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

First of all you should not  implements ICompensation in the bean class. Bean class will only contain getters, setters & constructor. You need to create another class which will implement the ICompensation. There you will write the code for calculations and other methods.

In database you can add another column "Role" which will define the employee role. By this approach you don't need to create extra methods such as QA, Developer, Manager.

please look into the following link. Here they tried to develop a login page using MVC model. You can just ignore the jsp pages and concentrate on controllers and beans. 
https://krazytech.com/programs/a-login-application-in-java-using-model-view-controllermvc-design-pattern

Comment: Thanks! ill look into that link. But what is  bean class btw, I dont know that yet, why it shouldnt implement an interface?

Comment: Hello, I am sorry for being late. First of all let me tell you about the bean class. It is a reusable software component. A bean encapsulates many objects into one object, so we can access this object from multiple places. Moreover, it provides the easy maintenance.

A bean class can implement interface. But not in your case. you don't need it here. Please look into the details form google.